# Imagem Corpo de Email - Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, envio-de-email

Estou com dificuldades em acoplar uma imagem no corpo do E-email usando a biblioteca padrão do code igniter.

Já fiz assim:

```
$cid = $this->email->attach('media/teste.jpg','inline');
$dados['cid']= $cid;
$emailbody = $this->load>view('proposta/template.php',$dados,true);
$this->email->message($emailbody);
```

Na view:

```
 <img src='cid:<?= $cid?>' alt="photo1" height="42" width="42" />'
```

No caso o anexo acontece, mas na view a imagem no corpo não aparece.

Alguém consegue ajudar?

Comment: você esta setando a imagem ? $mail->AddAttachment

Comment: ou $mail->AddEmbeddedImage

Answer (score 1):

Documentação:

```
$cid = $this->email->attachment_cid($filename);
$this->email->message('<img src="cid:'. $cid .'" alt="photo1" />');
$this->email->send();
```

Resolvido.